# Creating new groups with an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to create an array that will create new groups within the specific OU. If I populate the array with one site ex: `$site=@('Dallas')` it correctly creates the new groups, however if I place multiple sites in the array ex:`$site=@('Dallas','Bedford')`     Powershell return an error "Can not resolve directory object for given identity 'OU=Dallas Bedford, DC=examplecompany,DC=COM trying to list "Dallas Bedford" as the site. I have tried with single quotations and double quotations.

Here is the foreach statement

```
foreach ($location in $site) {$pc="OU=$site,OU=Location,DC=examplecompany,DC=COM"
```

How can I fix this so I do not have to manually enter the site location one by one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're embedding the collection itself (e.g $site) instead of $location which holds the current array element, try this:

```
foreach ($location in $site) {
   $pc="OU=$location,OU=Location,DC=examplecompany,DC=COM"
}
```